# Setting an Event to Null

Tags: c#, winforms, events, .net-4.0

I have a code like this:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    int _processProgress;
    public int ProcessProgress 
    { 
        get { return _processProgress; } 
        set 
        { 
            _processProgress = value; 
            if (ProcessProgressChanged != null) 
                ProcessProgressChanged(value);
        } 
    }

    public delegate void ProcessProgressChangedEventHandler(int progressPercentage);
    public event ProcessProgressChangedEventHandler ProcessProgressChanged;

    public void ClearProcessProgressChangedEvent()
    {
        this.ProcessProgressChanged = null;
    }
}
```

**Will it *unsubscribe* all method in the `ProcessProgressChanged` event when I call the `ClearProcessProgressChangedEvent()` method?**

My code is in C#, framework 4, build in VS2010 Pro, project is in Winforms.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate. In that question they are asking about setting the object - that is registered with the event - to null. This question they are asking about setting the event itself to null.

Comment: `ClearProcessProgressChangedEvent` can't be called from a destructor/finalizer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Well, it'll effectively clear the list of subscribers, yes (by setting the underlying delegate field to `null`) - so that the next time `ProcessProgress` is set, no handlers will be called. It's not really setting the *event* to `null` - it's setting the underlying field to `null`. It's just that the C# compiler is creating both an event (a subscribe/unsubscribe pair of methods) and a field (to store the handlers) using a single declaration.

You may find my [article about events and delegates](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx) useful.

Note that your event-raising code currently isn't thread-safe. I don't know whether it needs to be or not, but you might want to *consider* using:

```
set 
{ 
    _processProgress = value; 
    var handlers = ProcessProgressChanged;
    if (handlers != null) 
    {
        handlers(value);
    }
}
```

That way you won't get a `NullReferenceException` if the last handler is unsubscribed *after* the nullity check but *before* the invocation.

Comment: Will setting `this.ProcessProgressChanged = null;` cause a memory leak (that is, is this not a substitute for `-=`)?

Comment: @samis: It won't cause a memory leak, no.

Comment: Newer version of the Language allow you to write. handlers?.Invoke(value); For a null check instead of wrapping it in an if statement.

Comment: @Delta: Yup, but I don't go back over all my old answers every time there's a new language version...

Comment: That's fine I was mostly informing people that see this post in the future like I did and thought it could be helpful to those people :)

Comment: Currently Jon has 35,668 answers, phew :)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it will unsubscribe everyone from the event. There is a (bit indirect IMHO) reference to this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx):

> When all subscribers have unsubscribed from an event, the event
>   instance in the publisher class is set to `null`.

Comment: *"When all subscribers have unsubscribed from an event, the event instance in the publisher class is set to null."* - Is the converse true - does setting an event instance to null unsubscribe all the  subscribers (which may not apply in this specific case since it is a reference to an event, `this.ProcessProgressChanged`, that's being set to null)?

Comment: @samis if the reference is set to null, that means nothing references the combined delegate, so it will be garbage collected, and it won't prevent from garbage collecting of the subscribers. So, this simple thing, setting to null, unsubscribes all the subscribers.