# How to remove all event handlers?

Tags: .net, events, c#-4.0, delegates

Does setting the event to null effectively detach all targets?

```
public class Test
{
    public delegate void SomethingHappenedEventHandler(Test obj);
    public event SomethingHappenedEventHandler SomethingHappened;

    private void OnSomethingHappened()
    {
        if (this.SomethingHappened != null)
            this.SomethingHappened(this);

        //Once this event is fired, do not allow any more invocations!
        this.SomethingHappened = null;
    }
}
```

Instead of having to manually detach all events:

```
public class Thing
{
    priavte Test Testing { get; set; }

    public Thing()
    {
        this.Testing = new Test();
        this.Testing.SomethingHappened += DoSomething;
    }

    private void DoSomething(Test obj)
    {
        //Do some stuff.
        //Detach manually.
        this.Testing.SomethingHappened -= DoSomething;
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting an Event to Null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513292/setting-an-event-to-null)

Comment: This is almost always the wrong thing to do.  You don't know what code has subscribed the event.  Not an issue in the 2nd snippet, the subscriber is in control there.  If you want to stop raising an event then a simple bool gets the job done.

Comment: @HansPassant why is bad for an object to only allow an event to be fired once in this manner?

Comment: @HansPassant: If an object becomes aware that it will never have reason to fire an event in the future, does anyone benefit by having it keep references to the "subscribers"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `null` will effectively remove the subscribers from the list. The only thing you need to keep in mind is that the next time you raise that events, you could get a `NullReferenceException`. So since you're checking the value for `not null` you'll be fine, but make sure to check it each time you call it.

Comment: In `private void OnSomethingHappened()` I already check for null; I'm not sure what you mean by "consider creating a separate method for invoking that event which checks for null inside it" - thanks.

Comment: I'm noticing that even after nulling out the event, the invocation count still rises. Is this normal?

Comment: Sorry. As long as you invoke it by calling OnSomethingHappend() method you'll be okay. I read it quickly and didn't make that connection that you will only ever call OnSomethingHappened(). This is what I meant by having a method to call which invokes and validates the delegate

Comment: invocation count of the method you assign to your delegate? what is its value after nulling out the event?

Comment: I believe that was my mistake and the event was being fired multiple times in succession. Thanks for your help.